# int linux,i want to deploy qml dependency only , how to deploy content of json that obain from qmlimportscanner

Tags: linux, qt, qml

i run this

```bash
qmlimport scanner -rootPath  `myproject source` -importPat `qt installed path /qml/`
```

then get such as :

```json
[
    {
        "name": "QtQml",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQml",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.12"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuickLayoutsPlugin",
        "name": "QtQuick.Layouts",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Layouts",
        "plugin": "qquicklayoutsplugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "1.12"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuickControls2Plugin",
        "name": "QtQuick.Controls",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls.2",
        "plugin": "qtquickcontrols2plugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.12"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuick2Plugin",
        "name": "QtQuick",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick.2",
        "plugin": "qtquick2plugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.12"
    },
    {
        "name": "QmlCpp",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    {
        "name": "../Shapes",
        "path": "../subDir/dv_qmlLib/dv_qmlLib/ItemsControls/Shapes",
        "type": "directory"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuickTemplates2Plugin",
        "name": "QtQuick.Templates",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Templates.2",
        "plugin": "qtquicktemplates2plugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.5"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuick2WindowPlugin",
        "name": "QtQuick.Window",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Window.2",
        "plugin": "windowplugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.2"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuick2Plugin",
        "name": "QtQuick",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick.2",
        "plugin": "qtquick2plugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.0"
    },
    {
        "name": "../Shapes",
        "path": "../subDir/dv_qmlLib/dv_qmlLib/Buttons/Shapes",
        "type": "directory"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQmlModelsPlugin",
        "name": "QtQml.Models",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQml/Models.2",
        "plugin": "modelsplugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.12"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuick2WindowPlugin",
        "name": "QtQuick.Window",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Window.2",
        "plugin": "windowplugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.12"
    },
    {
        "name": "dv_qmlLib",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuickControls1Plugin",
        "name": "QtQuick.Controls",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls",
        "plugin": "qtquickcontrolsplugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "1.4"
    },
    {
        "name": "QtQuick.Controls.Styles",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "1.4"
    },
    {
        "name": "QmlCpp.Dv_ui.ViewModel",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuickLayoutsPlugin",
        "name": "QtQuick.Layouts",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Layouts",
        "plugin": "qquicklayoutsplugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    {
        "name": "..",
        "path": "../subDir/dv_qmlLib/dv_qmlLib/Themes",
        "type": "directory"
    },
    {
        "name": "../Js",
        "path": "../subDir/dv_qmlLib/dv_qmlLib/Themes/Js",
        "type": "directory"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QmlShapesPlugin",
        "name": "QtQuick.Shapes",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Shapes",
        "plugin": "qmlshapesplugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "1.12"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtGraphicalEffectsPlugin",
        "name": "QtGraphicalEffects",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtGraphicalEffects",
        "plugin": "qtgraphicaleffectsplugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtGraphicalEffectsPrivatePlugin",
        "name": "QtGraphicalEffects/private",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtGraphicalEffects/private",
        "plugin": "qtgraphicaleffectsprivate",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuick2WindowPlugin",
        "name": "QtQuick.Window",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Window.2",
        "plugin": "windowplugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.1"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuick2Plugin",
        "name": "QtQuick",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick.2",
        "plugin": "qtquick2plugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.11"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuickControls2Plugin",
        "name": "QtQuick.Controls",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls.2",
        "plugin": "qtquickcontrols2plugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.15"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuickLayoutsPlugin",
        "name": "QtQuick.Layouts",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Layouts",
        "plugin": "qquicklayoutsplugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "1.15"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuick2Plugin",
        "name": "QtQuick",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick.2",
        "plugin": "qtquick2plugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.15"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuick2WindowPlugin",
        "name": "QtQuick.Window",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Window.2",
        "plugin": "windowplugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.15"
    },
    {
        "name": "QtQml",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQml",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.15"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuick2Plugin",
        "name": "QtQuick",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick.2",
        "plugin": "qtquick2plugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.2"
    },
    {
        "name": "QtQuick.Controls.Private",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Private",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    {
        "name": ".",
        "path": "../TreeViewStyle.qml",
        "type": "directory"
    },
    {
        "name": ".",
        "path": "../QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Desktop/TreeViewStyle.qml",
        "type": "directory"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuickControls1Plugin",
        "name": "QtQuick.Controls",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls",
        "plugin": "qtquickcontrolsplugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "1.2"
    },
    {
        "name": ".",
        "path": "../QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Desktop/ComboBoxStyle.qml",
        "type": "directory"
    },
    {
        "name": ".",
        "path": "../QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Desktop/MenuBarStyle.qml",
        "type": "directory"
    },
    {
        "name": ".",
        "path": "../QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Desktop/TableViewStyle.qml",
        "type": "directory"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtLabsPlatformPlugin",
        "name": "Qt.labs.platform",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/Qt/labs/platform",
        "plugin": "qtlabsplatformplugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "1.1"
    },
    {
        "name": ".",
        "path": "../ComboBoxStyle.qml",
        "type": "directory"
    },
    {
        "name": ".",
        "path": "../MenuBarStyle.qml",
        "type": "directory"
    },
    {
        "name": ".",
        "path": "../TableViewStyle.qml",
        "type": "directory"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuickExtrasPlugin",
        "name": "QtQuick.Extras",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Extras",
        "plugin": "qtquickextrasplugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "1.4"
    },
    {
        "name": "QtQuick.Extras.Private",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Extras/Private",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuickLayoutsPlugin",
        "name": "QtQuick.Layouts",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Layouts",
        "plugin": "qquicklayoutsplugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "1.1"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuick2Plugin",
        "name": "QtQuick",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick.2",
        "plugin": "qtquick2plugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.5"
    },
    {
        "name": "QtQuick.Extras.Private.CppUtils",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "1.1"
    },
    {
        "name": "QtQuick.Extras.Private.CppUtils",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    {
        "name": "QtQuick.Controls.Styles",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "1.1"
    },
    {
        "name": ".",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Desktop/TreeViewStyle.qml",
        "type": "directory"
    },
    {
        "name": "QtQuick.Controls.Styles",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "1.3"
    },
    {
        "name": ".",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Desktop/ComboBoxStyle.qml",
        "type": "directory"
    },
    {
        "name": ".",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Desktop/MenuBarStyle.qml",
        "type": "directory"
    },
    {
        "name": ".",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Desktop/TableViewStyle.qml",
        "type": "directory"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtGraphicalEffectsPrivatePlugin",
        "name": "QtGraphicalEffects.private",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtGraphicalEffects/private",
        "plugin": "qtgraphicaleffectsprivate",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "1.12"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtGraphicalEffectsPlugin",
        "name": "QtGraphicalEffects",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtGraphicalEffects",
        "plugin": "qtgraphicaleffectsplugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "1.12"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuick2Plugin",
        "name": "QtQuick",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick.2",
        "plugin": "qtquick2plugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.1"
    },
    {
        "name": "HelperWidgets",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.0"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuickControls1Plugin",
        "name": "QtQuick.Controls",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls",
        "plugin": "qtquickcontrolsplugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "1.1"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuick2Plugin",
        "name": "QtQuick",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick.2",
        "plugin": "qtquick2plugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.3"
    },
    {
        "name": "QtQuick.Extras.Private",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Extras/Private",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "1.1"
    },
    {
        "name": "QtQuick.Controls.impl",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.12"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuickTemplates2Plugin",
        "name": "QtQuick.Templates",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Templates.2",
        "plugin": "qtquicktemplates2plugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.12"
    },
    {
        "name": "QtQuick.Controls.Fusion",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.12"
    },
    {
        "name": "QtQuick.Controls.Fusion.impl",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.12"
    },
    {
        "name": "QtQuick.Controls.Universal",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.12"
    },
    {
        "name": "QtQuick.Controls.Universal.impl",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.12"
    },
    {
        "name": "QtQuick.Controls.Material",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.12"
    },
    {
        "name": "QtQuick.Controls.Material.impl",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.12"
    },
    {
        "name": "QtQuick.Controls.Imagine",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.12"
    },
    {
        "name": "QtQuick.Controls.Imagine.impl",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.12"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuick2Plugin",
        "name": "QtQuick",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick.2",
        "plugin": "qtquick2plugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.4"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuick2Plugin",
        "name": "QtQuick",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick.2",
        "plugin": "qtquick2plugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.6"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuickControls1Plugin",
        "name": "QtQuick.Controls",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls",
        "plugin": "qtquickcontrolsplugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "1.5"
    },
    {
        "name": "QtQuick.Controls.Styles",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "1.2"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuickControls1Plugin",
        "name": "QtQuick.Controls",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls",
        "plugin": "qtquickcontrolsplugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "1.3"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQuick2Plugin",
        "name": "QtQuick",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick.2",
        "plugin": "qtquick2plugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.9"
    },
    {
        "classname": "QtQmlModelsPlugin",
        "name": "QtQml.Models",
        "path": "/home/deepvision/Qt5.12.6/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQml/Models.2",
        "plugin": "modelsplugin",
        "type": "module",
        "version": "2.2"
    }
]
```

There are the qml files of my project, the qml files of the qt installation directory, and the plug-ins of the qt installation directory.

how do i copy  those dependencies to my app workDir ,
my dynamic libraries using LD_LIBRARY env variable locate. so i need qml dependencies only.

i tried using `linuxdeployqt` , but our company's project put a lot lib in a dir(git repo),not each dynamic libray  is used in my branch, so i get a lot error such `xxx not found` when use `linuxdeplyqt`

i just need copy qml dependencies to my app work dir

my files tree :

```bash
../
dv-detector/
| .git/
| .vscode/
| docs/
| dv_algorithm/     =>a loat of librays
| dv_base/          =>a loat of librays
| dv_business/      =>a loat of librays
| dv_ui/
| | bin/            => application work here ,also deploy target dir
| | configuration/
| | data/
| | defectpic/
| | depends/
| | dv_ui/
| | extension/
| | features/
| | image/
| | image_nologo/
| | p2/
| | plugins/
| | qtpropertybrowser/
| | readme/
| | src/
| | subDir/
| | | dv_core/
| | | dv_qmlLib/                =>  qml libray project as .pri
| | | | dv_qmlLib/
| | | | | Buttons/
| | | | | Charts/
| | | | | DbgTools/
| | | | | ItemsControls/
| | | | | Js/
| | | | | Shapes/
| | | | | Svg/
| | | | | Themes/
| | | | | Window/
| | | | | qmldir                => qmldir
| | | | window/
| | | | dv_qmlLib_global.h
| | | | dv_qmllib.h
| | | | eventHub.h
| | | | qmlUtility.h
| | | | qmlbootstraper.h
| | | | dv_qmllib.cpp
| | | | eventHub.cpp
| | | | qmlUtility.cpp
| | | | qmlbootstraper.cpp
| | | | dv_qmlLib.pri
| | | | dv_qmlLib.qrc
| | | test/
| | dv_ui.h
| | dv_ui.cpp
| | .git*
...
...
...
```

Comment: Can we (1) see a directory tree, (2) confirm that you set PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH correctly prior to running your executable, (3) do you know about or set QML2_IMPORT_PATH, (4) do you know about qt.conf?

Comment: 1） i has update to this quesion  2) i import LD_LIBRAY_PATH ，app can run up and widget part work well , only qml  get "xx module not install" .3) i write it in dv_qmlLib.pri， QML_IMPORT_PATH = $$PWD  QML2_IMPORT_PATH = $$PWD   4)i almost do not use it ,only use it when in windows setting dpi   5. thank you

Comment: Oh, correction on 1. I need to see the directory tree on `linuxdeployqt` or `windeployqt`. Particularly where the libraries are (i.e. DLL on Windows, or .so on Linux).

Comment: i use github release page laster   version , it is packed as  appimage ,  just.  i use it to deploy my application ,it can't found some  libray that not exsist my computer ,but use  `lld` inspect those libraries that in dv_base  dv_algorithm dir  can see them.   this is why i don't want use linuxdeployqt to deploy my app, because it will scan all  libraries,for example,  one of them has a link to  xx.so.2  ,but i have xx.so.1 only. i can't found a way only deploy qml dependencies use linuxdeployqt T-T

Answer (score 0):

finally  , i use windeployqt deploye it , and in linux , copy plugins and qml module those have the same names to my app work dir .  and edit `run.sh` add lines to  export `QML2_IMPORT_PATH`  `QT_PLUGIN_PATH` point to them .  and it can be run up.   still notice some libraies are miss , after a little bit of copy stuff, i it work well

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).